# Reading a .csv file into R which contains comma separated values in single observation cells

Tags: sql, r, csv

I have a .csv file I want to read in to my R environment which has comma separated observations but also contains some observations which have multiple values which are comma separated. So e.g.

```
 clothes,colours,size 
 shirt,blue,green,grey,small
 shirt,yellow,black,small
 shorts,blue,medium
 shorts,black,large
```

where in row 1, there are 3 values for column 2, and in row 2, there are 2 values for column 2. When read in with a comma separator, it gives me:

```
clothes    colours    size 
 shirt      blue      green    grey    small
 shirt      yellow    black    small
 shorts     blue      medium
 shorts     black     large
```

There are unfortunately no spaces between the comma separated values within the .csv file.

Is there any way to stop the grouped values for column 2 from separating into more columns without adjusting the original .csv file? My file is approx. 10GB and I wanted to automate the read in using read.csv.sql() (I'm also subsetting the data for specific observations in the data, which I have managed to get, but due to the columns not matching for all rows, the code stops after a certain number of rows is checked).

Thanks in advance!

I've tried creating multiple separators or working with SQL code when using read.csv.sql(). Unfortunately, I don't have enough SQL knowledge to know more than basic code.

Comment: Welcome to SO, wwandw! It may be easier if we see "real" CSV contents instead of a representation of it. Can you [edit] your question and replace (or augment) the sample data with a few lines each of straight CSV text?

Comment: Unfortunately that won't be possible due to the nature of the data file

Comment: How so? If it's proprietary data, then make something up. If it's not proprietary, why is it a problem to get the first few lines?

Comment: If you can't provide sample data in the question (preferred), is there a link to the data?

Comment: Is the question saying that there are 3 fields and spaces separate the fields with commas separating the subfields?  If that is what you have it is not a csv file.

Comment: Adding to what the others have commented, consider the following 2 theoretical representations of a row from your csv file
"shirt,blue,green,grey,small" or "shirt,  blue,green,grey,  small".  In the first case, there is no information for a computer to figure out which commas are "real" and which are not.  In the second, "real" commas have white space after them, while the ignorable commas do not.  In this case, you can use a different method to read in the data (fixed width or space deliminated, for example), then remove any trailing commas

Comment: Is there any way to specify or flag which commas should be classified as  "real" in the first case? I am unable to edit the original file, any editing would have to be done as its being read in.

Comment: Not directly.  this is why sharing an example is so important.  (No one cares about whether it is your real data, it just needs to be representative.)  If you know the set of possible values for each column, you can look for those code words.  If you are dealing with fixed width data, you can use that information.  It depends on your data

Comment: Do you want only R or SQL answers, or is it possible to use other tools to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comments, you have to have something to go on.  Computers aren't smart enough to "know" what goes where.  Without any other guidelines, you are going to need to use your knowledge of the options for each column - with all the pitfalls therein.  (Let's hope none of your columns can have typos).

Here's a way to use context to get everything into the right column:

```
library(tidyverse)

definitions <- list(
  clothes =  c("shirt", "shorts"),
  colours = c("blue", "green", 'gray', 'grey', 'yellow', 'black', 'red', 'orange'),
  size = c("small", 'medium', 'large')
)


# example data
csv_text <- "
 clothes,colours,size 
 shirt,blue,green,grey,small
 shirt,yellow,black,small
 shorts,blue,medium
 shorts,black,large
"

# use this with a file location
# raw_input <- scan(file = file_location, what = 'character')

# use this for text as above
raw_input <- scan(text = csv_text,what = "character")

# parse the results
result  <- definitions |>
  imap_dfc(
    ~ str_extract_all(raw_input[-1], paste(.x, collapse = "|")) |> 
      as_tibble_col(column_name = .y)
  ) |>
  unnest(c(clothes, size)) |> # Quick way to simplify columns where all columns have one entry
  mutate(
    colour_recovered = map_chr(colours, ~ paste(.x, collapse = ","))  # recover commas if desired
  )
```

Again, this is completely dependent upon the options in all the columns being known or parse-able - but it can work at least for the toy example.

Answer (score 0):

Although this could be done within R (as shown in the last section below) since this is a very large file it is likely much faster preprocessing it outside of R first to get into a reasonable format.

First determine how many fields there are. We can do that from within R.

```
max(count.fields("mufile.csv", sep = ","))
```

Then place the gawk program shown below in a file, process.awk, and edit the  line that starts with `header=` to put in a header with that many fields.  On each row the gawk program adds commas to the last comma (or at the end if there are no commas in that row) to fill it out.  gawk tends to be quite fast. Now we run it.

gawk itself is on most Linux systems and on Windows you can find it in [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) which you should install if you haven't already.  This assumes you have placed gawk on your PATH but if not then use its path to when referring to it.  This is run from the shell or cmd line, not from R.

```
gawk -f process.awk myfile.csv > myfile2.csv
```

Finally read myfile2.csv into R using `read.csv` (base R), `read.csv.sql` (sqldf), `fread` (data.table) or `read_csv` (readr).

### gawk program

```
# To run: gawk -f process.awk myfile.csv > myfile2.csv
# To configure: edit header= line as needed
BEGIN { 
    header = "clothes,colour1,colour2,colour3,size" 

    commas = gensub(/[^,]/, "", "g", header)
    ncommas = length(commas)
    FS = OFS = ","
}
NR == 1 { print header; next } # skip input header; use header var instead
{ 
  if (NF > 1) print gensub(",", substr(commas, 1, ncommas - NF + 2), NF-1)
  else print $0 commas
}
```

### Example

For example, if our file is this

```
clothes,colours,size 
shirt,blue,green,grey,small
shirt,yellow,black,small
shorts,blue,medium
shorts,black,large
```

Then running the `max(...)` line from gives

```
max(count.fields("myfile.csv", sep = ","))
## [1] 5
```

and we can just use the header shown above since it already defines 5 column names.  Running the `gawk ...` line above gives this output

```
clothes,colour1,colour2,colour3,size
shirt,blue,green,grey,small
shirt,yellow,black,,small
shorts,blue,,,medium
shorts,black,,,large
```

### Just R

This is unlikely to be as fast in terms of runtime but if you want to try a pure R approach

```
File <- "myfile.csv"

nflds <- count.fields(File, sep = ",")
mx <- max(nflds)
hdr <- c("clothers", paste0("colour", seq(mx-2)), "size")
L <- readLines(File)
L2 <- ifelse(nflds > 1, 
  mapply(sub, "(.*),", paste0("\\1", strrep(",", length(hdr) - nflds + 1)), L),
  paste0(L, strrep(",", length(hdr)-1)))
L2[1] <- paste(hdr, collapse = ",")

# DF <- data.table::fread(text = L2) # likely faster
DF <- read.csv(text = L2)
```

With the file shown above it gives:

```
> DF
  clothers colour1 colour2 colour3   size
1    shirt    blue   green    grey  small
2    shirt  yellow   black          small
3   shorts    blue                 medium
4   shorts   black                  large
```